# How to read all the text in edittext using cpp?

Tags: android, c

I am trying to set the baud-rate of "/dev/ttyS4" and return the Text(EditText) using C code with the help of JNI in android studio

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DEBUG 1

#if DEBUG
#include <android/log.h>
#  define  D(x...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"hello-jni",x)
#else
#  define  D(...)  do {} while (0)
#endif

char*  str;
char buffer[512];

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_android_uart_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */, jstring text)
{
    {
        asprintf(&str, "Hi\n");
        strlcpy(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
        free(str);

        int ttyFD = 0;
        struct termios tty;
        const char *stringInC = env->GetStringUTFChars(text, NULL);
        auto SampleCmd = stringInC;
        int i_WriteBytes = 0;

        memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

        ttyFD = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDWR| O_NONBLOCK | O_NDELAY );

        if(ttyFD < 0)
        {
            asprintf(&str, "Error in opening /dev/ttyS4\n");
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);


        }
        else
        {
            asprintf(&str, "ttyS4 port opened successfully\n");
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);
        }
        if (tcgetattr ( ttyFD, &tty ) != 0 )
        {
            asprintf(&str, "Error from tcgetattr\n");
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);

        }
        cfsetspeed(&tty, B0);


        tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;                            /* parity */
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                            /* stop bits */
        //tty.c_cflag   &=  ~CSIZE;                             /* */
        tty.c_cflag |= CS8;                                /* data bits */
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;                           /* no hardware flow control */
        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);            /* no s/w flow ctrl */
        tty.c_lflag = 0;                                  /* non canonical */
        tty.c_oflag = 0;                                  /* no remapping, no delays */
        tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;                                  /* read doesn't block */
        tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;                                  /* read timeout */
        tty.c_cflag |=
                CREAD | CLOCAL;                     /* turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines */
        tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);    /* */
        //tty.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;                           /* */

        tcflush(ttyFD, TCIFLUSH);

        if (tcsetattr(ttyFD, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
            asprintf(&str, "Error from tcsetattr\n");
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);
        }

        i_WriteBytes = write(ttyFD, SampleCmd, sizeof(SampleCmd) - 1);
        asprintf(&str, "written bytes = %d\n", i_WriteBytes);
        strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
        free(str);

        if (i_WriteBytes < 0) {
            asprintf(&str, "failed to write value on port\n");
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);
        }
        sleep(1);
        char read_buf[1024];
        memset(&read_buf, '\0', sizeof(read_buf));
        int num_bytes = read(ttyFD, &read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));

        if (num_bytes < 0) {
            asprintf(&str, "Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
            strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
            free(str);
        }
        asprintf(&str, "Read bytes = %i \n Received message: %s", num_bytes, read_buf);
        strlcat(buffer, str, sizeof buffer);
        free(str);

        close(ttyFD);

        return env->NewStringUTF(buffer);
}
```

My problem is that WriteBytes and Read bytes only take 7 bytes of the edittext"Text" and it only display 7 characters of it.
What i want is to display the entire "Text" from the EditText.

This is the result iam getting:

```
**Input:**
EditText(baud Rate)=0
EditText(message) =this is a test app

**Output:**
TextView(Details)
hi
ttyS4 port opened successfully
written bytes = 7 
Read bytes =7
Received message:this is
```

Comment: C or C++? Please remove one of the tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: How exactly do you see 'that WriteBytes and Read bytes only take 7 bytes of the edittext"Text" and it only display 7 characters of it'. Does the problem depend on the use of JNI? If not, please try to make a [mre] in pure C without the JNI dependency. Note that `auto` in C is not the same as in C++. `auto SampleCmd = stringInC;` is the same as `int SampleCmd = stringInC;`. `sizeof(SampleCmd) - 1` is not related to the length of a string, it is the size of an `int` variable. (In C++ it would be the size of a pointer variable.)

Comment: @Bodo Please check the **asprintf** statement which is bellow the "i_WriteBytes" , that is `asprintf(&str, "written bytes = %d\n", i_WriteBytes);`.thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
        i_WriteBytes = write(ttyFD, SampleCmd, sizeof(SampleCmd) - 1);
```

is wrong.

Variable `SampleCmd`, defined as

```
        const char *stringInC = env->GetStringUTFChars(text, NULL);
        auto SampleCmd = stringInC;
```

is of type `int` in C or type `const char *` in C++. (Note that `auto` is an old keyword in C which defines a storage class  is the default for variables inside functions and forbidden at file scope. As you don't specify a type, it defaults to `int`.)

The value `sizeof(SampleCmd)` is not related to the length of the string pointed to by `stringInC`. It is the size of a variable of type `int` (in C, or type `char*` in C++). Apparently this size is 8 on your platform, so you will *always* write 7 bytes.

You could use

```
        i_WriteBytes = write(ttyFD, SampleCmd, strlen(SampleCmd));
```

or use `fdopen` on `ttyFD` and use output functions from `stdio.h`.

Comment: thank you for the answer, this `i_WriteBytes = write(ttyFD, SampleCmd, strlen(SampleCmd));` worked

Comment: @ShakthiPrasadS Then you can accept the answer by clicking on the check mark. This will mark your question as answered.